# Elasticsearch query on array of objects with date

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Hi i am new to Elasticsearch and trying to implement a solution using `spring-data-elasticsearch`. My indexed data looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "worker": "A",
    "availability": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020-01-12",
        "endDate": "2020-02-12"
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2020-04-12",
        "endDate": "2020-05-12"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "worker": "B",
    "availability": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020-04-12",
        "endDate": "2020-11-12"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

By referring the elastic docs i planned on using range query to fetch the records for a specified rage of dates, for example i wanted to fetch the available worker between "2020-05-12 to 2020-06-12". This is the query that i formed:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "query": {
                            "range": {
                                "availability.start_date": {
                                    "from": "2020-05-12T00:00:00.000Z",
                                    "to": "2020-06-12T00:00:00.000Z",
                                    "include_lower": true,
                                    "include_upper": true,
                                    "boost": 1.0
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "availability",
                        "ignore_unmapped": false,
                        "score_mode": "none",
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

The above query shows empty hits when its executed, but when i use the dates that is indexed then i am able to get the records (ex if i specify the dates as "2020-04-12 to 2020-11-12" the worker B results are displayed). As per the range query it should have worked for my earlier case as-well if i am not wrong. Is there anything wrong in the approach that i followed. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no worker whose `start_date` (!!) is between `2020-05-12` and `2020-06-12`. I think you need to proceed differently for what you're trying to achieve.

Since you're trying to match on ranges, it would probably be easier to leverage the [`date_range` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html). Your mapping should look like this:

```
PUT your-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "availability": {
        "type": "date_range", 
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can index all your worker's availabilities like this:

```
{
  "worker": "A",
  "availability": [
    {
      "gte": "2020-01-12",
      "lte": "2020-02-12"
    },
    {
      "gte": "2020-04-12",
      "lte": "2020-05-12"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "worker": "B",
  "availability": [
    {
      "gte": "2020-04-12",
      "lte": "2020-11-12"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then you can perform the search you want like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "availability": {
        "gte": "2020-05-12",
        "lte": "2020-06-12",
        "relation": "contains"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you'd find only worker B satisfies the condition.

**UPDATE**

Your query in Java needs to be like this:

```
    final BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

    queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "A"));

    RangeQueryBuilder availability = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("availability")
           .gte(query.getStartDate())
           .lte(query.getEndDate());

    queryBuilder.must(availability);

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);

    // @formatter:off
    return new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withPageable(pageable)
            .withQuery(queryBuilder)
            .build();
```

Comment: Hi @Val i tried your approach but i am getting an exception like `org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=error parsing field [availability.gte], expected an object but got gte]`

Comment: You must have missed a step, can you double check? I tested the above and it worked out. Can you tell which version of ES you're using?

Comment: Hi @Val here is a minimum reproduction of the project https://github.com/sandeepsuvit/search-poc
Would you be kind enough to point me in the right direction, do let me know if i am missing something in the configuration.

Comment: Kudos for this!!! [this](https://github.com/sandeepsuvit/search-poc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/search/documents/Worker.java#L25) should be of type `FieldType.Date_Range`, you don't need class `Availability`, it should simply be a Map with a `gte` and `lte` keys

Comment: Hi @Val thanks for checking, but when i try to index as an array of `availability` its throwing an error like: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>` out of START_ARRAY token (through reference chain: com.search.documents.Worker[\"availability\"])

Comment: Is your repository updated? Why is the Map value a String and not a Date? Your [test search query](https://github.com/sandeepsuvit/search-poc/commit/1c6cf36ce6e4fa305809676d1d535faa0d642776#diff-7ff7aebca7b1a795431898fce777fac00a6b71373935bb17023b13e1051b2202R61-R65) is not correct by the way

Comment: The error you get is because `availability` should actually be `List<Map<String, String>>` or `List<Map<String, Date>>`

Comment: Oops sorry that was my mistake. Corrected it now and updated my repo. I am able to index the data now and query the results. This is the query that i am forming now. Is this correct?
```java
final RangeQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("availability");
  queryBuilder.gte(query.getStartDate());
  queryBuilder.lte(query.getEndDate());

return new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(queryBuilder)
    .build();
```

Comment: Great! As I commented earlier, your query is not correct. I've updated my answer to show you the right way.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for that, really appreciate it. Now its working perfect. I do have one more question if I may. If say suppose I need to add one more field called `partial: true` to `availability` indicating that a worker is only available partially on a particular day and I wanted this flag also to be a query parameter, how different would that be? 
I think we cannot add it to the `date_range` map object `availability` in that case right?

Comment: Oh i get it. Something like this right?
```java
public class Availability {
 @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
 private boolean partial;
 
 @Field(type = FieldType.Date_Range, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd")
 private List<Map<String, LocalDate>> dates;
}

...
// Then in the parent Worker.java mapping to Availability
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
private List<Availability> availability;

```

Comment: Just `private Map<String, LocalDate> dates;` inside `Availability` because at the Worker level you have a List of `Availability` already

Comment: Exactly. That was a typo my bad, I have updated my code. Is that what you are referring to bytwy?

Comment: Yes, that's correct now. And since you've introduced a nested type, now the query will need to be nested as well, but that's easy to do

Comment: Hi @Val, I updated my query in the code and I guess its correct from a nested perspective. But the results doesn't show up now. Is it because of the query formed?
```java
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("availability.partial", query.isPartial()));
   
   RangeQueryBuilder availability = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("availability.dates")
             .gte(query.getStartDate())
             .lte(query.getEndDate());

     queryBuilder.must(availability);
```

Comment: Would you ming creating a new question (with properly formatted code), this one is getting crowded :-)

Comment: Sure would love to do that. Here is the reference to that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679710/elasticsearch-query-on-array-of-composite-objects-along-with-date-ranges

Comment: Was it for me? I upvoted your answer already

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that option on the screen though. Done! :) and thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Thank you very much!