# Elasticsearch query on array of composite objects along with date ranges

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hi I have a question on how to create an elastic search query for a nested composite object with date ranges and additional field parameters like so

```json
[{
            "name": "A",
            "availability": [
                {
                    "partial": true,
                    "dates": {
                        "gte": "2020-12-01",
                        "lte": "2020-12-02"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "availability": [
                {
                    "partial": true,
                    "dates": {
                        "gte": "2020-12-05",
                        "lte": "2020-12-06"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "partial": false,
                    "dates": {
                        "gte": "2020-12-08",
                        "lte": "2020-12-11"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
```

This is my entity data

```java
@Document(indexName = "workers")
public class Worker {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<Availability> availability;
}

public class Availability {
    @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
    private boolean partial;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date_Range, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd")
    private Map<String, LocalDate> dates;
}
```

This is the search query that I have currently written, but the results come as empty

```java
         final BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("availability.partial", query.isPartial()));
         
         RangeQueryBuilder availability = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("availability.dates")
                   .gte(query.getStartDate())
                   .lte(query.getEndDate());
queryBuilder.must(availability);
        
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);

        // @formatter:off
        return new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withPageable(pageable)
                .withQuery(queryBuilder)
                .build();
```

This is my query dto

```
public class WorkerQuery {
    private boolean partial;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
}

// Request data
{
    "partial": true,
    "startDate": "2020-12-01",
    "endDate": "2020-12-02"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great start!! You're just missing a `nested` query since `availability` is `nested`. The Java query needs to be like this:

```
final BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("availability.partial", query.isPartial()));

RangeQueryBuilder availability = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("availability.dates")
               .gte(query.getStartDate())
               .lte(query.getEndDate())
               .relation("within");
queryBuilder.must(availability);

final NestedQueryBuilder nested = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("availability", queryBuilder);

Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);

// @formatter:off
return new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withPageable(pageable)
            .withQuery(nested)
            .build();
```

Comment: You are a life saver @Val :) Now its working as expected. But I have one question on the query that you have formed above. Is it necessary that the `nested` query be the root query object? Can that be applied only on the nested `availability` object alone?

Comment: I've added it to the root because you don't have any other constraints. If you were to add a constraint on the `worker` field, then you'd need a root bool query and the nested query would become a component of it along with the new constraint on the top-level worker field

Comment: Got it :) Thanks a lot for the info provided

Comment: Hi @Val I have updated my query [here](https://github.com/sandeepsuvit/search-poc/blob/0bde2fcaed8829ccd7e7358701b424539d976e12/src/main/java/com/search/services/impl/WorkerServiceImpl.java#L70) Let me know if I am doing it right?

Comment: I have tried querying it, and seems like its returning the results back. But one thing I found strange about the query is, say if I am doing this query - `startDate of 2020-12-02 and endDate of 2020-12-05` I am getting both Worker A & Worker B results. But logically that shouldn't happen right, since we are looking for dates in-between the indexed dates which aren't available.

Comment: Hmm, right, I missed the `.relation("contains")` part (it's `intersect` by default). See my updated answer

Comment: I updated the code adding `.relation("contains")` and now the results are not showing up at all :(

Comment: Do you mind updating the code in your repo?

Comment: Did that already. Also I did try `.relation("WITHIN")` and this seems to be working. Is this correct bytwy?

Comment: Right, it's the [other way around](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html), `within` is the right relation to use, good catch!

Comment: Got it :) Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could be of help!

Comment: Hi @val i did have one more follow up question/issue based on the improvisations i was doing on the same code. Can i ask that here or should i create another question? :)

Comment: It's always best to keep questions concise, so when answered, please create a new one. Thanks for your understanding ;-)

Comment: here is the reference link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691864/elasticsearch-query-issue-on-date-time-ranges-in-a-nested-object