# Elasticsearch query issue on date-time ranges in a nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hi I am using spring data Elasticsearch to form a query and have the following data indexed in my elastic search

**Indexed Data**

```json
[
        {
            "id": "Ef5E-HYB3sZzelDP-ie1",
            "name": "B",
            "availability": [
                {
                    "partial": false,
                    "dates": {
                        "gte": "2020-12-05T09:00:00",
                        "lte": "2020-12-10T13:00:00"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "Ev5F-HYB3sZzelDPIicy",
            "name": "A",
            "availability": [
                {
                    "partial": false,
                    "dates": {
                        "gte": "2020-12-01T07:00:00",
                        "lte": "2020-12-02T12:00:00"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**Entities**

```java
public class Worker {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<Availability> availability;
}
```

```java
public class Availability {
    @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
    private boolean partial;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date_Range, format = DateFormat.date_hour_minute_second)
    private Map<String, LocalDateTime> dates;
}
```

**Query Condition:** I wanted to query and check if there are any worker available between the date-times:

```
{
    "startDate": "2020-12-05T09:00:00",
    "endDate": "2020-12-10T10:00:00"
}
```

For this I am creating a query using bool query and nested query like so:

```java
private Query prepareSearchQuery(final WorkerQuery query, Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) {
        final BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

        // To form the nested query
        NestedQueryBuilder nested = prepareAvailabilityQuery(query);

        queryBuilder.must(nested);

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);

        // @formatter:off
        return new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withPageable(pageable)
                .withQuery(queryBuilder)
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    /**
     * Query to prepare the nested object structure
     * 
     * @param query
     * @return
     */
    private NestedQueryBuilder prepareAvailabilityQuery(final WorkerQuery query) {
        final BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

        // Add date query
        if (isValidDateTime(query.getStartDate(), query.getStartDate())) { // validate the datetime obj
            // @formatter:off
            RangeQueryBuilder dateQuery = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("availability.dates")
                    .gte(query.getStartDate())
                    .lte(query.getEndDate())
                    // This is not working with date-time
                    .relation("WITHIN");
            // @formatter:on

            queryBuilder.must(dateQuery);
        }

        return QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("availability", queryBuilder, ScoreMode.None);
    }
```

For this particular case when I comment out the `relation("WITHIN")` I am able to fetch the result for my query condition, but when the relation is included in the query, it doesn't return any result. Is there something wrong with the query?

**Note:** I have also added converters to convert date-time to Long and Back while reading and writing the data.

Here is the [repository for this](https://github.com/sandeepsuvit/search-poc/blob/fc3b5190efed219752a36c16a3f1745f99db03d1/src/main/java/com/search/services/impl/WorkerServiceImpl.java#L89) for reference

**UPDATE**

I updated my search query to consider the `timezone` and `format` of the data that is indexed.

```java
private NestedQueryBuilder prepareAvailabilityQuery(final WorkerQuery query) {
        final BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        
//      queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("availability.partial", query.isPartial()));
        
        // Add date query
        if (isValidDateTime(query.getStartDate(), query.getStartDate())) {
            // @formatter:off
            RangeQueryBuilder dateQuery = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("availability.dates")
                    .gte(query.getFormattedStartDate())
                    .lte(query.getFormattedEndDate())
                    .format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
                    .timeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
                    // This is not working with date-time
//                  .relation("WITHIN");
            // @formatter:on

            queryBuilder.must(dateQuery);
        }

        return QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("availability", queryBuilder, ScoreMode.None);
    }
```

So the elastic query that is getting formed now is like this for the range-query alone:

```json
{
    "range": {
        "availability.dates": {
            "from": "2020-12-01T07:00",
            "to": "2020-12-02T12:00",
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true,
            "time_zone": "Asia/Kolkata",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm",
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

Index mapping in elastic search for `worker` index

```json
{
    "workers": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "_class": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "availability": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "dates": {
                            "type": "date_range"
                        },
                        "partial": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "routing": {
                    "allocation": {
                        "include": {
                            "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "refresh_interval": "1s",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "workers",
                "creation_date": "1610515965426",
                "store": {
                    "type": "fs"
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "gJ9zzWs1RXmevJbwwj9Z2g",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7100199"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you model `Availability.dates` as a `Map` and not as a class with two properties `gte` and `lte`? I have an example using int ranges here https://www.sothawo.com/2020/09/how-to-use-elasticsearchs-range-types-with-spring-data-elasticsearch/, this might help

Comment: So to sum up, [`within` was working with a `LocalDate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679710/elasticsearch-query-on-array-of-composite-objects-along-with-date-ranges), but it doesn't work with `LocalDateTime`? Any chance you can print out the query that's being generated?

Comment: Hi @Val I have printed the query [here](https://github.com/sandeepsuvit/search-poc/blob/07be92b41c897da2f316206d0c44ef74be8f80f1/src/main/java/com/search/services/impl/WorkerServiceImpl.java#L72) both with and without `relation:within`

Comment: Ok, the difference is that in your documents the dates have no timezone, while in your query the from/to dates are interpreted in the default timezone `Z`, so you should try to store your availability dates with a timezone

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Thanks for the providing me the example link. I do agree with your point of moving it to a class which is something I plan on doing. But in my usecase i am storing the data with the same `gte` and `lte` field names like you have in your `Term` class. So I guess it wouldn't make any difference. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: But @Val as per the [docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) the [`Format=date_hour_minute_second`](https://github.com/sandeepsuvit/search-poc/blob/07be92b41c897da2f316206d0c44ef74be8f80f1/src/main/java/com/search/documents/Availability.java#L28) i am using should contain only `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` right. Not sure where the `Z` is coming from. Should i use some other format for this case?

Comment: you define the date format in the `@Field` annotation for Spring Data Elasticsearch to know how to format the date. But you build the query with a native Elatsicsearch query builder that has no information about this format specification.

Comment: @Val I have made few updates to the [code here](https://github.com/sandeepsuvit/search-poc/blob/36a4084904db5afcb24258c5424a832afc134354/src/main/java/com/search/services/impl/WorkerServiceImpl.java#L169) and I am using the default `intersects` relation for my search case which you can see  in the `UPDATE` section above. The issue now is: if I search within the date-rage its giving me results, which is correct. But if I search outside the range say `startDate:2020-12-01T14:00, endDate: 2020-12-02T15:00` its giving me Worker A's result, which I find incorrect. Anything you see missing?

Comment: Just to make sure, can you show the real index mapping that has been created by Spring Data ES?

Comment: @Val I have updated the index mapping above. Please check

Comment: Ok, thanks, at least we're sure the mapping is correct

Comment: Yes I did cross check that. But there isn't any formatter applied in the mapping right? Because all I see is just `"type": "date_range"` and I guess ES leaves the formatting to us while querying.

Comment: To me this is a timezone issue. If I modify your range query with `time_zone: Europe/London` (because your document dates are in that timezone) you'll see that the hours match

Comment: So do you recommend to store the datetime information along with the timezone while indexing? Because right now I am storing only till `2020-12-01T07:00` and this doesn't contain timezone information.

Comment: For the date format you should probably use `date_time` or `date_time_no_millis` which are the same as what you have but include the timezone component

Comment: Have you tried the date formats I suggested?

Comment: Hi @Val i tried with `basic_date_time_no_millis` but this doesn't index the date and time together, it just indexes the date part alone. The request that i send was this: `{"name":"A","availability": [{"dates": {"gte": "2020-12-05T09:00:00","lte": "2020-12-10T13:00:00"}}]}` but it got indexed like this: `{"id": "UPsMAXcB78AETQCA4CX1","name": "A","availability": [{"partial": false,"dates": {"gte": "2020-12-05","lte": "2020-12-10"}}]}`

Comment: Not `basic_date_time_no_millis` but `date_time_no_millis` (the separators are different). Also make sure to start from a freshly created index

Comment: Yes i tried that aswell `@Field(type = FieldType.Date_Range, format = DateFormat.date_time_no_millis)` but getting the same result just as date after indexing. Is it something to do with the request i am sending `gte: 2020-12-05T09:00:00 and lte: 2020-12-10T13:00:00`